# Error create login using codeigniter V.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to migrate from CodeIgniter version 2 to version 3 , but when I try to log it turns out there is a problem, but the same script and when it is run versioned 2 there is no problem ? there anything you can help

This my error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: username
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 27

This my controllers

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index($param='') {

        if($param == 'error')
            $param == 'Incorrect username or password';
                   if($param == 'error1')
            param == 'User not acctive';    
        
        $data = array('title'=>'KOPKAR - Login','message'=>$param,'base_url'=>base_url());
        $this->load->view('login/login', $data);

    }

    public function do_login() {

        $data = $this->input->post(null,true);
        $is_login = $this->db->get_where('user',array(
                                        'username'=>$data['username'],
                                        'password'=>md5(trim($data['password']))
                                        ))->row();
        if($is_login){
            
            $session_set = array(
                
                'is_login'  => true,
                'nik'       => $is_login->nik,
                'username'  => $is_login->username,
                'id_user'   => $is_login->id_user,
                'lastlogin' => $is_login->lastlogin,                
                'jabatan'   => $is_login->jabatan
            );
            $this->db->update('user',array('lastlogin'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('id_user'=>$is_login->id_user));
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_set);
            redirect('home');
        }else{
            
            redirect('login/index/error');
        }   
    
}   

}
```

Comment: set `false` here and check `$this->input->post(null,false);`

Comment: @Saty thanks for your comments but it did not work,

Comment: `print_r($data)` and check the value of it!!

Comment: `print_r($is_login)` too.

Comment: @all same it did not work,

Comment: @irwan Dwiyanto what is the result of `print_r($data)`

Comment: @naseebac just any word Array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
public function do_login() {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password'); 
        $is_login = $this->db->get_where('user',array(
                                        'username'=>$username,
                                        'password'=>md5(trim($password))
                                        ))->row();
        if($is_login){

            $session_set = array(

                'is_login'  => true,
                'nik'       => $is_login->nik,
                'username'  => $is_login->username,
                'id_user'   => $is_login->id_user,
                'lastlogin' => $is_login->lastlogin,                
                'jabatan'   => $is_login->jabatan
            );
            $this->db->update('user',array('lastlogin'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),array('id_user'=>$is_login->id_user));
            $this->session->set_userdata($session_set);
            redirect('home');
        }else{

            redirect('login/index/error');
        }
```

i'm adding this

```
 $username = $this->input->post('username');
 $password = $this->input->post('password');
```

and remove this

```
$data = $this->input->post(null,true);
```

Comment: yes it's work thanks @naseba c, but if wrong username/password redirect('login/index/error');  keep repeating,

example : http://localhost/barcode/login/incorect/login/login/do_login?username=&password=admin

Comment: i try redirect(base_url().'/login/index/error') but error, Message: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: i think you missing  this `;`